# How can I generalize this code so that it works not only for whitespace?

Tags: haskell

I made this function, that works the same way as `words` in Haskell,

```
words' [] = []
words' str = before : words' (dropWhile isSpace after) where
    (before, after) = break isSpace str
```

and I'm now trying to generalize it so that if I type in:

```
gWords'  "abcbdecefab" "ac" == ["b","bde","ef","b"]
```

or

```
gWords'  "abc(hjd(hj))jk)k" "()" == ["abc","hjd","hj","jk","k"]
```

Comment: It looks like you need to replace `isSpace` by something more generic.

Comment: yeah I know, but i dont know with what.. @mkrieger1

Comment: Hint: take a look at `elem`: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:elem

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I can't seem to find out how to use elem, pretty new at Haskell

Answer (score 1):

Idiomatic Haskell is to provide a predicate (i.e., boolean function) as an argument:

```
wordsBy _ [] = []
wordsBy isbrk str = before : wordsBy isbrk (dropWhile isbrk after) where
    (before, after) = break isbrk str
```

Then, you can provide a specific predicate:

```
gwords' str brks = wordsBy (`elem` brks) str
```

To explain the predicate above:

- the function `elem` returns true if its first argument can be found in the list provided as its second argument:

  ```
  elem e brks
  ```
- Haskell has an alternate infix format, to treat functions as operators:

  ```
  e `elem` brks  ===  elem e brks
  ```
- Haskell also has a "slice" notation to partially apply operators; you can view it as shorthand for a commonly used lambda form:

  ```
  (`elem` brks)  ===  (\ e -> e `elem` brks)
  ```

which gives you the desired predicate:  one that returns true for characters in the string `brks`.